# QlikView line charts single data points not visible after distributing to Access Point.

Tags: qlikview

Line chart works well in the desktop version, shows even a single data point properly. First i thought it needed a symbol for the data point and may be with a bigger size, so i added a "dot" and increased its size to 4pt but still facing the issue. Anybody faced this problem with QV11?

Comment: Check to ensure all the same selections are active in Access Point. I've had this happen when I didn't realize a selection was/wasn't made in a field.

Comment: The selections didn't seem to be a problem. I checked the same on both QV desktop and access point versions. No luck.

Comment: What happens if you change the object from line chart to straight table?

Comment: i see the raw numbers correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround for this at https://community.qlik.com/thread/88010

1. Chart → Properties → Axes tab→ Dimension axis →  deselect "Continuous"
2. General tab→ change the chart type to - bar chart
3. Presentation tab → select "show All Bars" in bar settings section
4. General tab→ change the chart type back to - line chart
5. click Apply.